# opacity with CSS (if possible with Bootstrap v4)

Tags: css, opacity

I'm trying to get opacity to work on the cards but as far as I know I have to use CSS since BS v4 doesn't have it. In CSS opacity doesn't seem to be working.

```
<div class="jumbotron big-banner" style="height: 100vh">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center mt-5">
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Login</h5>
            <p class="card-text">
              <label for="signUpUsername">Username</label>
              <input type="form-input" class="form-control" id="signUpUsername">
              <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword">
              <small id="passwordHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Never share your password.</small>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Submit</button>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Sign-Up</h5>
            <p class="card-text">
              <label for="signUpUsername">Username</label>
              <input type="form-input" class="form-control" id="signUpUsername">
              <label for="signUpPassword">Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="signUpPassword">
              <small id="passwordHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Never share your password.</small>
              <label for="inputFirstName">First Name</label>
              <input type="form-input" class="form-control" id="signUpFirst">
              <label for="inputLastName">Last Name</label>
              <input type="form-input" class="form-control" id="signUpLastName">
              <label for="inputBio">Bio</label>
              <input type="form-input" class="form-control" id="signUpBio">
              <small id="bioHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Enter a description. Other users will see
                this.</small>
            </p>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

IN CSS

```
.card-body {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

I tried applying it to different divs but opacity still doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, Bootstrap v4 does not have Opacity utility classes this [feature was added in Bootstrap v5.1](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/opacity/)

You could however easily add this to your global site stylesheet in order to create them

```
.opacity-0 {
  opacity:0!important;
}
.opacity-1 {
  opacity:0.2!important;
}
.opacity-2 {
  opacity:0.4!important;
}
.opacity-3 {
  opacity:0.6!important;
}
.opacity-4 {
  opacity:.8!important;
}
.opacity-5 {
  opacity:1!important;
}
```

[Codepen Example using your Html](https://codepen.io/davidsielert/pen/BaGbvwv)